# Enabling Parameter based on the Value of Another Parameter in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with two parameters. The second parameter is only relevant if the first parameter has a particular value. I would therefore like to disable that second parameter unless the first parameter has the proper value.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169.aspx) was the answer - cascading parameters.